# What is the default plugin folder location in QGIS 3?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, directory

I am searching for default location for QGIS 3 Plugin folder

I checked here but could not find:

- `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.0\apps\qgis\python\plugins`
- `C:\Users\Abhijit\.qgis2` (cannot locate `.qgis3`,  should it be there ?)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Go to menu `Settings` -> `User profiles` -> `Open active profile folder`

From there, you can go to `python` -> `plugins`. That's the plugin folder for QGIS v3.

On my GNU/Linux machine:

```
/home/USER/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins
```

On a Windows machine:

```
 C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins
```

In those paths, `USER` will change by yours and `default` might change as well if you're using another profile.

Comment: Thanks for the step by step instructions . by any chance is the documentation for new QGIS ready ? any link will help.

Comment: Plugins directory may not exist so pastable path for current Windows user:
 ```%APPDATA%\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\```

Comment: On Mac with QGIS3.6 , it was `~/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins`

Comment: this is useful for debugging - just change the name of the plugin folder if you are having trouble getting QGIS to load due to a plugin you just installed

Comment: Thanks. I have found it in `$HOME/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins`