# Loading GeoTrace plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation

I want to load the GeoTrace plugin into QGIS. I have donwloaded the ZIP file, unzippped it and created a folder `C:\Users\UserName\.qgis2\python\plugins\GeoTace` and copied the files in there. I still can't see the plugin if I click on plugins in the GUI. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Which version of qgis are you using? If you are using QGIS 3 you need to change the location of the plugins folder see [QGIS 3 Plugin folder location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274311/qgis-3-plugin-folder-location)

You should be able to install geotrace using the qgis plugin repository.

Answer (score 3):

GeoTrace plugin doesn't work in QGIS 2.x. `C:\Users\UserName\.qgis2` folder contains files/folders related to QGIS 2.x. You should visit the link @Lachlan specified in his/her answer.

[image]