# Downloading and saving plugins for QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-plugins

I have downloaded a plugin from [QGIS](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/fresh/) website, and save it on me desktop as a ZIP file. Then, I uploaded it with the Plugin "Install from ZIP" function.
Then, I uploaded it with the Plugin "Install from ZIP" function.

[image]

Can I delete the ZIP folder from me desktop or should I save it in the QGIS folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the zip file, as its contents are copied into your local QGIS configuration directory.

Where this directory is located was answered [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/274311/qgis-3-plugin-folder-location).