# Getting to the code of a QGIS 3 plugin

Tags: qgis, plugins

So I installed a QGIS plugin and want to look how this plugin works internally. I have installed it within QGIS using the 'manage and install plugins' functionality.

In the installation folder I looked for the code of the plugins. I found the QGIS 3.4\apps\qgis\python\plugins folder and found most of my other plugins there. But not the one that I am looking for.

Is there any other location to look?

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/274311/49538

Comment: Can you specify the OS you are using and the plugin you want to inspect ? You can download plugins directly from the official depot : https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/.

Comment: found it there. Thanks!!